# Is there way to pass path parameter in Mountbank

Tags: mountebank

I was trying to pass path parameter using Mountebank.

Below is working, but there path is static no any parameters.

```
"predicates": [
            {
              "equals": {
                "method": "GET",
                "path": "/accounts",
                "query": {
                  "permissionId": "xxx"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "responses": [
            {
              .....            }
          ]
```

In case if I need to do `GET /accounts/[account-no]` where `account-no` is a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex worked, Please note use `matches` in case of regex instead of `equal`

```
"predicates": [
            {
              "matches": {
                "method": "GET",
                "path": "/accounts/\\d+",
                "query": {
                  "permissionId": "xxx"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "responses": [
            {
              .....            }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the path param explicitly like:

```
"path": `${someBasePath}/${path.param}/${somethingElse}`
```

It'd work if you knew its value. Otherwise, your predicates will be as simple as this:

```
[{"matches": {"method": "GET", "path": "\/accounts\/.*"}}]
```

TY